# Reorder UITableViewCell while dragging another cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to reorder a cell while another one is being dragged. Mainly the reason for this is because only two cells are allowed in the first section so whenever you try to remove cell out of the first section the first cell of the second sections needs to come up or if you try to put a cell from the second section to the first section the last cell of the first section needs to go down to the second section.

Now i managed to do the logic to recognise when i need to push the other cell away inside the `- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath` method but when ever i try to call `[self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:currentPath toIndexPath:pushAwayPath]` i got that famous error saying there is incosistency between added/removed cells and sections although the i also update the data source correctly.

[image]

Whenever you try to move **Options 0 1** to the place of **Option 1 0**, the **Option 1 0** should come to the place of **Option 0 1** and the other way around so there will be always two options in the firrst section

Comment: `UITableView` doesn't really support what you want while the cell is being dragged around by the user. You would need to move the additional cell via code after the user completed the move of the original cell.

Comment: @maddy i was afraid of that answer :( Is it at least possible to catch a Drag Start event so to hide the section headers before dragging starts and then display them again when it is finished?

Comment: No, the API doesn't support any sort of pre or post move events.